# How can I populate ASP:treeview with database query, only child populate? c# (WEB)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, treeview

How can i populate asp:treeview only child populate with database query like "Select Database_Name from database where user_id='1' and show these database in child treeview.Here is image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Idk.png)

I want "Database" remain same and blow child "Database Name",,only 1st 3 records replace with "Database Name" shown just,Kindly tell me how can i do this,Thanks.I search on google but i can't find solution.Here is my db pic 
[dbimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK5cm.png).
Here i try :

```
       SqlConnection cnn=new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void PopulateTreeView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT Database_Name FROM  Create_db",cnn);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
Master.FindControl("TreeView1");
    TreeView tv = (TreeView)Master.FindControl("TreeView1");
TreeNodeCollection parentNode = tv.Nodes;
 SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(dt);
 PopulateTreeView(parentNode,0, dt);// error come at parent node
}
```

Here is my aspx

```
     <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" 
                    Font-Size="Larger" onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
                    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                    <Nodes>
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Database" Value="Database">
                            <asp:TreeNode  Text="Database Name" Value="Database Name"></asp:TreeNode>
                            <asp:TreeNode Text="Database Name" Value="Database Name"></asp:TreeNode>
                            <asp:TreeNode Text="Database Name" Value="Database Name"></asp:TreeNode>
                            <asp:TreeNode Text="More" Value="Database Name"></asp:TreeNode>
                        </asp:TreeNode>
                    </Nodes>
                    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" 
                        HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" 
                        HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                </asp:TreeView>
```